# continuous time markov process - first passage time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a continuous time-homogeneous Markov diffusion process such that $X_0=y$. Let $$p(x,t|y)=d\Pr(X_t\le x|X_0=y)/dx$$ be the respective transition probability density. Let $$T_{y,a}=\inf\{t\ge0\colon X_t\ge a\}$$ Would it be correct to claim that
$$
\Pr(T_{y,a}>\tau)=\int_{-\infty}^a p(x,\tau|y)\,dx,
$$
or what's the connection between $\Pr(T_{y,a}>\tau)$ and $p(x,\tau|y)$?

Comment: No. Two problems: this $p(x,t\mid y)$ is not a transition probability density. If $p(x,t\mid y)$ was the transition probability density of $X_t$, then the RHS of the formula suggested for $\Pr(T\gt \tau)$ would not be $\Pr(T\gt \tau)$ but $\Pr(X_\tau\lt a)$.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the definition of $p(x,t|y)$ to make it a density. How does one find $\Pr(T>\tau)$ from $p(x,t|y)$?

Comment: Think you're just computing the probability X is below a at time tau, not that it was below it for the whole time interval.

Comment: It's the transition probability density that satisfies the same forward and backward equations but the boundary conditions need to reflect that $X=a$ is a cemetery state.